# ¿Como crear espacios entre un código y otro en plena ejecución?

Tags: python

recién voy empezando en el mundo de la programación, el hecho es que cuando ejecuto esto en el cmd de windows (al hacer doble clic en el archivo.py) todo esta junto, como ven no importa cuantos espacios ponga entre el 1 primer print y el 2, siempre salen uno bajo el otro.
¿Es posible que habrá algún código para que deje algunos espacios al ejecutar?.
Gracias de Antemano. :)

```
def suma(x, y):
    return x + y

print(suma(12,12)) #PRIMER PRINT




print(suma(1,2)) #SEGUNDO PRINT

print(suma(10,10)) #TERCER PRINT

input()

SALIDA:
24
3
20
```

Comment: solo utiliza print(suma(10,10)+"\n") donde `\n` es el numero de espacios que quieres separar.

Comment: El título no es el más apropiado. No quieres crear espacios entre códigos, sino imprimir líneas en blanco. Un simple `print()` sin argumentos te imprime una línea vacía. Un carácter `\n` dentro de una cadena también representa un retorno de carro. Puedes hacer `print("\n"*5)`, por ejemplo, para imprimir 5 líneas vacías. Las líneas en blanco que metas dentro de tu código fuente son ignoradas por Python. Sólo sirven para organizar mejor el código pero no afectan a su funcionamiento.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigos, ahora es simple, es mas era obvio creo yo. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El print tiene el argumento `end` que por defecto es el salto de línea ('\n'), por eso pone uno sólo. Como lo mencionaron en los comentarios, puedes agregar al final de tu texto el número de saltos de línea extras que quieras. Por ejemplo, para tener 4 saltos de línea (tres en tu texto más el que tiene el print por defecto):

```
print('algo\n\n\n')
```

También puedes modificar el argumento `end` y puedes tomar ventaja de la multiplicación de strings para obtener el número de saltos de línea que desees. El siguiente ejemplo imprime lo mismo que el anterior pero es más sencillo controlar el número de espacios que quieres después de tu texto

```
print('algo', end='\n' * 5)
```